# Error al mapear en TypeScript

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript, map

Tengo un método en TypeScript (Fastify) por el cual mapeo un array de objetos y trabajo con cada item dentro de un map para luego hacer un return con un objeto después de haberlo construido dentro de la función. En este caso, y a través de un console.log antes del return he visto que los objetos se construyen bien, pero no me permite introducir los objetos porque me da el siguiente error:

```
El tipo 'Promise<LuggageDetailNumbilResponseDTO>[]' no se puede asignar al tipo 'LuggageDetailNumbilResponseDTO[]'.

 Al tipo "Promise<LuggageDetailNumbilResponseDTO>" le faltan las propiedades siguientes del tipo "LuggageDetailNumbilResponseDTO": idBag, cin, totalWeight, numBags y 4 más.ts(2322)
```

Y el método es el siguiente:

```
const generatePassengerDetails = async (
  listLuggage: modelIndex.DBObject[],
  authorization: string
) => {
  let response = new modelIndex.LuggageDetailNumbilListResponseDTO();

  response.passengers = listLuggage.map(async (item) => {

    const auxPaxkey = item.paxkey.toString();
    const auxFltkey = item.fltkey.toString();

    const dataDb = await boardingDb.decryptDataByPax(auxPaxkey, auxFltkey);

    let nompax = String(modelIndex.getPassengerData.dateDBtoDataResponse(dataDb).name);
    let apepax = String(modelIndex.getPassengerData.dateDBtoDataResponse(dataDb).surname);

    return generateLuggageDetail(item, nompax, apepax, authorization);
  });

  return response;
};
```

No entiendo el error, ya que, como digo, al mirar los objetos devueltos me salen correctamente pero el response.passenger me aparece con el error que indiqué más arriba.

¿A qué se debe y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Falta la definición de `generateLuggageDetail()`. A parte de eso, estás trabajando con llamadas asíncronas que devuelve promesas y no los datos finales. Es decir, un `async (parámetro) => { instrucciones }` devuelve una promesa, y no un dato final.

Comment: No entiendo ¿Entonces cómo hago que me admita ese Promise? Disculpa, pero acabo de empezar con Typescript. ¿Y a qué te refieres con la definición de generateLuggageDetail()? Gracias.

Comment: Usas `return generateLuggageDetail(item, nompax, apepax, authorization);` y podemos suponer qué valor devuelve, pero no lo indicas. Se puede usar `Promise.all()` para realizar lo que deseas o iterar sin usar `Array.map()`. ¿Qué solución prefieres?

Answer (score 2):

Voy a asumir que la función `generateLuggageDetail` devuelve un objeto del tipo `LuggageDetailNumbilResponseDTO`:

Tienes un array de objetos del que, mediante una transformación (un mapping) quieres obtener un array de objetos de otro tipo. Hasta ahí todo bien:

```
let arrayResultado: Tipo1 = arrayOriginal.map(tipo1ATipo2);
```

El problema es que para hacer la transformación requieres hacer llamada asíncrona. Por tanto, decides usar `async/await`. Una función declarada como asíncrona **siempre** devuelve una **promesa**:

```js
let devuelveDos = async () => 2;

devuelveDos()
.then(console.log);
```

Por tanto, no estás obteniendo un array de objetos del tipo que quieres, sino un **array de promesas** del tipo que quieres. Así tienes que esperar que estas se resuelvan. Pero incluso entonces, ya que has tenido que declarar tu método (`generatePassengerDetails`) como async, lo que obtendrás será una promesa:

```js
let devuelveMasDos = async a => a + 2;


const numeros = [1,2,3,4];
async function main () {
  let promesas = numeros.map(devuelveMasDos);
  //promesas es un array de promesas, esperamos a que se resuelvan
  let resultados = await Promise.all(promesas);
  return resultados;
}

//ahora, en lugar de un array de promesas, tenemos una promesa de un array
main().then(console.log);
```

Por tanto necesitarás hacer algo como:

```
 let details = await generatePassengerDetails(datos, auth);
```

o

```
 generatePassengerDetails(datos, auth)
   .then(details => ...);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos. Con lo que me ayudasteis lo solucioné.

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucióne haciendo:

```
response.passengers = await Promise.all([...])
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo funciona tu código. Lee [answer]. Si la otra respuesta te ha sido útil, [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: Veo que has optado por `Promise.all()`. ¿Sabes cómo funciona para arreglarte el problema?